# Ping in startup script

Tags: powershell-2.0

Can ping command be used in a startup script to check connectivity to a network server ?
Powershell startup script:

```
$Ping=new-object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
$Reply=$ping.send("MyServer01")
if ($Reply.status() -eq "Success")
{
Perform operations
}
Else
{Perform other operations}
```

Rightnow, the $reply is blank during startup script execution but has values if I run after logged in.

Thanks.

Comment: use `test-connection` instead...

Comment: It didn't work as well. If ((test-connection "MyServer01" -quiet) -eq "True")

Comment: wasn't a solution, just a comment...

Comment: Any other suggestions? The purpose is to check if the machine is connected to corporate network during startup. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Test-Connection should work just fine, but it doesn't return the string "True", rather the boolean $True.  So:

```
if (Test-Connection "MyServer01" -Quiet) {
    Some-Command
} else {
    Other-Command
}
```

This works perfectly fine on my box (W2K3, Powershell 2, .NET 4.5).

PS: if you just run `cmd`, `ping MyServer01`, does it work then?